# Url rewriting strategies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

My URL now are `domain/{country}/{culture}/{catalog}/{index}`

Now I need to cut {country} slug.

Which is the best way to:

1. Trace all old URL
2. Redirect with a `301` to new URLs...

Where  to manage this stuff (I don't want to manage via IIS)?

Global.asax?